# SQL top 3 most recent records by group

Tags: mysql, sql, apache-spark

I have a table with a date column and a string column. I'm trying to filter the string column to the most recent 3 records.

```
+----------+--------------+
|   date   |    string    |
+----------+--------------+
|2000-11-14|           AAA|
|2009-11-07|           AAA|
|2020-11-20|           AAA|
|2019-11-07|           AAA|
|2018-11-07|           AAA|
|2020-11-22|           BBB|
|2019-11-20|           BBB|
|2018-11-20|           BBB|
|2014-11-21|           BBB|
|2016-11-22|           CCC|
|2017-11-08|           CCC|
|2018-11-07|           CCC|
|2019-11-22|           CCC|
|2020-11-09|           CCC|
|2020-11-11|           DDD|
+----------+--------------+
```

The final table would look like this:

```
+----------+--------------+
|   date   |    string    |
+----------+--------------+
|2020-11-20|           AAA|
|2019-11-07|           AAA|
|2018-11-07|           AAA|
|2020-11-22|           BBB|
|2019-11-20|           BBB|
|2018-11-20|           BBB|
|2020-11-09|           CCC|
|2019-11-22|           CCC|
|2018-11-07|           CCC|
|2020-11-11|           DDD|
+----------+--------------+
```

I don't think I can use `MAX(date)` by group here, since I'm trying to get the top 3 most recent records (not top 1).

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Spark?  They're not the same thing.

Comment: Sorry, I'm using Spark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ROW_NUMBER` analytic function is particularly well suited to this type of problem:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY string ORDER BY date DESC) rn
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT date, string
FROM cte
WHERE rn <= 3;
```